# C++: What is wrong with the output?

Tags: c++

This code should output 0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1, instead it outputs zeros. Why is that?

Define a function u(x)=x;

```
void pde_advect_IC(double* x, double* u)
{
  int N = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]); //size of vector u
  for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
    u[i] = x[i];
}
```

Here is the implementation:

```
int main()
{
  double a = 0.0;
  double b = 1.0;
  int   nx = 4;
  double dx = (b - a) / double(nx);
  double xx[nx + 1]; //array xx with intervals

  // allocate memory for vectors of solutions u0
  double* u0 = new double [nx + 1];

  //fill in array x
  for (int i = 0; i <= nx; i++)
    xx[i] = a + double(i) * dx;

  pde_advect_IC(xx, u0); // u0 = x (initial conditions)
  for (int i = 0; i <= nx; i++)
    cout<<u0[i]<<endl;

  // de-allocate memory of u0
  delete [] u0;
  delete [] u1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: what is `sizeof(x)`

Comment: `sizeof(x) == sizeof(double*)` which is 4 or 8 (depending on your system). `sizeof(x[0]) == sizeof(double)`, most likely 8. Thus `N` is either 0 or 1.

Comment: @MarkoTunjic the `for` loop actually works, since the size of `xx` is `nx + 1`. Condition  `i < nx` is actually WRONG.

Comment: @Michael But the OP also has i<=N in the first function.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `sizeof(x)` because that will return the size of the pointer, not the array you thought you passed to it. You have to specify the size with a third parameter or use something more convenient like an `std::vector` and use `size()`.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void pde_advect_IC(double* x, double* u, const int& N)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    u[i] = x[i];
}

int main()
{
  double a = 0.0;
  double b = 1.0;
  int   nx = 4;
  double dx = (b - a) / double(nx);
  double xx[nx + 1]; //array xx with intervals

  // allocate memory for vectors of solutions u0
  double* u0 = new double [nx + 1];

  //fill in array x
  for (int i = 0; i <= nx; i++)
    xx[i] = a + double(i) * dx;

  pde_advect_IC(xx, u0, nx + 1); // u0 = x (initial conditions)
  for (int i = 0; i <= nx; i++)
    cout << u0[i] << endl;

  // de-allocate memory of u0
  delete [] u0;

  return 0;
}
```

Note that I added `const int& N` to `pde_advect_IC()` in order to pass it the size of the array, by `const reference`, to be sure it does not get modified by mistake.
Note that your trick with `sizeof()` does **not** work with pointers.

Comment: You probably should ask this in a separate answer. If one of this answers has solved your problem, accept it. I will be more than happy to check your outputs, even if I have no idea about how Matlab works.

Comment: I actually solved it! it was just a mistake in the sine phase!
Thanks again!